# Handling different models in one form submission rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes, controllers

I have been trying to build an app offering discounted vacation trips such that:
(1) a user(travel agent) can compose a trip by combining hotels (hotel chains) and cities
(2) a user(regular user) can review hotels and cities, s/he has already visited.
(3) another user can evaluate how good the deal is with respect to the country and hotel the travel agent will have him/her stay.

The models look like this

`class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :trips
  has_many :reviews
end`

`class Trip < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :hotel
  belongs_to :city
end`

`class Hotel < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :city
  has_many :reviews, as: :reviewable
end`

`class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :hotels
  has_many :reviews, as: :reviewabel
end`

`class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :reviewable, polymorphic: true
end`

The problem is I can figure out how to create the controllers for Hotel and City because they are only created in the context of a makeshift trip. I checked the rails casts on nested forms and the use of `accepts_nested_attributes_for` but I can't seem to get it right.

Note: the reason why I separated the hotels and the cities is to be able to retrieve the reviews independently. Such that Say I enjoyed my stay at the Four Seasons in Toronto but not the one in NY. - because of the cities/hotels (=> accommodating the case where I didn’t enjoy it because the hotel was crap and the one where I didn’t because the city was)

Note 2: I understand it doesn’t make much sense to seperate hotels and cities in this example - I made a mistake in self-appointing the tutorial. But the problem has been haunting me, what if it was an delivery order instead with entree/meal/dinner instead of hotels and cities, or restaurant chains and neighborhoods.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you

**Edit**

Edited after Settheline’s comment.

I mean the create actions for cities and hotels only exist in the context of a Trip create action. 
Trip has 2 attributes: title & description: It’s only then that I “log” the itinerary. Here’s what my controllers look like to give you a better idea

```
class TripsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :signed_in_user

  def show
    @trip = Trip.find(params[:id])
  end

  def index
    @trips = current_user.Trip.all
  end


  def new
    @trip = Trip.new
  end

  def create
   # @trip = Trip.new(trip_params)
   @trip = current_user.trips.build(trip_params)
   if @trip.save
     flash[:success] = "Your trip was successfully published!"
     redirect_to @trip
   else
     render 'new'
   end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
   if @trip.update_attributes(trip_params)
     flash[:success] = "Trip was updated"
     redirect_to @trip
   else
     render 'edit'
   end
  end

  def destroy
   Trip.find(params[:id]).destroy
   flash[:success] = "trip was deleted. Thank you"
   redirect_to @user #root_url
  end

  private

     def trip_params
       params.require(:trip).permit(:title, :description)      
     end  
end

class CitiesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :signed_in_user

  def create
    @city = City.new(city_params)
    if @city.save
      # flash[:success] = ""
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  # def destroy
  #  City.find(params[:id]).destroy
  #  flash[:success] = “City was deleted."
  #  redirect_to root_url 
  # end

   private

     def city_params
       params.require(:city).permit(:name, :province, :country)
     end

 end


class HotelsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :signed_in_user

  def create
    #similar to city
  end

  def destroy
    #similar to city
  end

  private

    def hotel_params
      params.require(:hotel).permit(:name, :address,
                                              :management_contact,
                                             :city_id)
    end
end
```

And here’s the problem:
I want to have/add create forms within the trip one in

```
sample_app/app/views/trips/new.html.erb

<% provide(:title, 'New Trip') %>
<h1>New Trip</h1>
<div class="row">
  <div class="span6 offset3">
    <%= form_for(@trip) do |f| %>
      <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

      <%= f.text_field :title, placeholder: "Type in a title" %>
      <%= f.text_field :description, placeholder: "Any additional info." %>

      <%= f.submit "Publish", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't create the controllers? Like `rails g controller Hotels`? Not understanding the problem you're facing exactly - can you explain?

Comment: I edited the original post with my views and controllers. Let me know if it's still unclear, and thank you for taking the time to help.

Answer (score 0):

`accepts_nested_attributes_for` allows you to save attributes on associations. Although you do have associations in your models it doesn't necessarily mean that you need to use `accepts_nested_attributes_for`. It depends on how the code flows through your controllers.

#### Simple Example

For example, you would probably want to allow your users to view their trips and reviews. First you'll need a method to get the current user:

**users_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id])
  end
end
```

This method will be inherited by all of your controllers and allow them to get the current user. (There are many solutions out there for getting the current user, this is definitely not a good solution but it is OK for demonstration purposes).

**Trips & Reviews**

Now you can create some controllers for the current user to view their trips and reviews:

**trips_controller.rb**

```
class TripsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @trips = current_user.trips.all
  end
end
```

**reviews_controller.rb**

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @reviews = current_user.reviews.all
  end
end
```

Now you have some controller actions displaying the trips/reviews for the current user. I think this example demonstrates how you can create your controllers and that `accepts_nested_attributes_for` is not necessarily required.

Comment: I apologize I wasn't clear enough in the original post. I have edited the question to include my views and controllers hope it's better now. I'm having trouble with the create Trip action/form as I can't figure out how to include the City and Hotel forms.

What you said about the use of accepts_nested_attributes_for got me thinking, I'm gonna check my rails 4 way copy, there's probably something I am missing or a mistake in my models.

Thank you for taking the time to answer.